# How to implement Android In App Subscription API for monthly subscription of my application?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have made an application which I want to publish on Google Play and want to set monthly subscription plan for this app. For example first month I will give app as trail for one month and after that every month I will charge $1 to use my application service. I have studied about Android In App Subscription API but not able to understand the whole concept. Now my question are?

1. How to handle the trial of application.
2. How to make payment when trail is over?
3. Hoe to handle the subscriptions?

What possible changes I have to make in my current application. Please assist me.
Thanks.

Comment: You got any solution for this?could you please post it here,Thanks.

Comment: yeah i have implemented subscription method but sure whether its accurate or not. because i did not test it on live environment due to some other important work...