# Android paid app with subscription

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I wish to launch a paid app but want the upfront payment should be valid only for 1 year. So basically am looking a combination of paid app with annual subscription. I know i can use these 2 options independently but can someone please suggest if combination of both is possible on android play store

Comment: It looks like the api supports deferment, so you could sell the app and defer the subscription for a year : http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html
Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18170460/2033671

Comment: thanks Austin for the response, it can surely help . But how will user know that upfront payment he/she is  making is not a one time payment, it has to be done every year. Is there any provision during payment process to notify this to user. I assume all google users will have a understanding that which app is paid , will require only 1 time payment. Or you know any app having this payment strategy?